# Handle WPF button click and enable disable

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a UI with a few controls.

1. Initially when form loads, search button will be disabled, once all
   search criteria are given, search button will be enabled
   automatically.
2. On click on search button, I want to call the method
   using MVVM pattern and bind the result in grid

XAML:

```
<Button Name="btnGetDetails" Content="Get Details" Grid.Row="2" Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"/>
```

What code is required in model, view model and XAML?

Comment: What problem did you run into?

Comment: @Trickery, to be very honest, problem is that I dnt know how to do that, only know how XAML will look like, but do not know how it will be implemented in model and view model. searched some article, but not getting good link.... Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code have you tried in model, view model and XAML?  Post what you've done.

Comment: @BigDaddy, As I mentioned in my query, I do not know what code will be there in model, view model, even a sample will work... I will get idea.. can you pls help?                                                          class Model
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }

    }

Class ViewModel
{


}

Comment: @Amit [WPFTutorial.net](http://www.wpftutorial.net/). StackOverflow is not a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Command will be executed only when the button will be clicked on. If you need to do something to the button then you should do it to the Window that contains the button (assuming your button is in a Window). Now if you want to stick with the MVVM pattern then you should not use the Window.OnLoaded, because that would put code in your code behind. One option is to use System.Windows.Interactivity, which you have download seperately. Here is what it will look like:

```
<Window x:Class="..."
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="clr
        -namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ...}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Window>
```

As for what your Model, View and ViewModel should be, I think you should check out some tutorials on the web. There are some very good explanations on how to implement the MVVM pattern. I found this youtube video pretty informative myself:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpGvqVtSYjs

Answer (score 0):

So some MVVM basics here.  You're on the right track, just missing a step.  Your Command implementation in your view model should (potentially) accept two inputs: An Action representing the executing code, and a Predicate that returns true/false on whether you can execute the code in the Action block.  So, in your view model, define your command along the lines of (note: this is a sample from one of my projects):

```
this.executeCommand = new RelayCommand(this.OnExecuteClicked, this.OnCanExecuteChanged);
```

The OnCanExecuteChanged method will return a bool based on whatever criteria you set up.  So, if you want the submit button enabled when property A and property B have been properly set up, then return true, else return false.  The internal workings of your command implementation will take care of the rest.  Do a search for a RelayCommand implementation (if you don't have it already) or a DelegateCommand for further samples.